# How to check to see if a treemap is empty in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way that I can check to see if a tree map is empty or not?

my code never enters to the following for loop if the tree map is empty.

```
for (Map.Entry<BigInteger, ArrayList<BigInteger>> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
      if (entry.getKey() == FirstModulus) {
    ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    list = myMap.get(FirstModulus);
    list.add(gcd);
 } 
      else {
    ArrayList<BigInteger> list = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
    list.add(gcd);
    myMap.put(FirstModulus, list);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah: `myMap.isEmpty()`. Please read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)!

Comment: Be careful adding to a map while iterating over it...

Answer (score 2):

```
myMap.isEmpty()
```

`TreeMap` extends [AbstractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html) and therefore inherits all of its defined methods. You won't see `isEmpty()` in the `TreeMap` documentation because it is defined in its parent class and there was no need to override it since the same means of determining if a map is empty can be used.